Should the tags be "Sensation" and "Perception" or "Sensation and Perception"
This question uses a "perception" tag. Generally Sensation and Perception are treated as one as an area of interest and I wouldn't trust the average person to appreciate the distinction between the two. Should we instead use a sensation-and-perception or sensation-perception tag for this?

Er, that question doesn't use the sensation tag... wrong link?

@zergylord I meant perception, I must have confused myself because Sensation is always said first

People qualified to be experts or at least students of cog sci should know the difference between sensation and perception. Isn't that the quality of content we would expect as a minimum? 
IMO can see combining the tag for this instance, but as a matter of policy we shouldn't enable or encourage amateur questions not knowing the fundamentals. 

It's not an issue of "dumb people don't know the difference so let's help them" and I didn't mean to phrase it as such; the two are just generally said in the same breath as a general interest category (after all separating them usually isn't wanted).

These are clearly different concepts (no need to go back to William James), although I agree they are often associated.(1) The best solution could be to create two separate but cross-linked tags. 
As as sidenote, "the average person" might not be aware of that 'fine' distinction, or might even be tempted to tag his/her question sensation when its content has to do with e.g., self-perceived health state ("I feel blue today").

(1) I would expect those two tags will often appear in conjunction with experimental design or psychophysics.
